# keep writing API responses to json file

Tags: python, json

How can I keep writing to same json file from API endpoint, I tried the following

```
import json
index=1
with open('data.json','w') as f:
    while True:
        di=get_url(index) #returns json from local API endpoint
        if not di:
            print("Completed")
            break
        data=di['data']
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        index+=1
```

When I open it in Firefox, it gives `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2882 column 2 of the JSON data` .

I tried writing each response into a file and they work fine, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why don't you go and check the line 2882 of `data.json`?

Comment: @HarshalParekh it is a space

Comment: Could you upload `data.json` so that we can replicate the error?